# Correct form of multiplicative Holt-Winters

Tags: exponential-smoothing

In [forecasting principles and practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/holt-winters.html), the update equations are given as:

$$l_t = \alpha\frac{y_t}{s_{t-m}} + (1-\alpha)(l_{t-1} + b_{t-1})$$
$$b_t = \beta^*(l_t-l_{t-1}) + (1-\beta^*)b_{t-1}$$
$$s_t = \gamma\frac{y_t}{l_{t-1}+b_{t-1}} + (1-\gamma)s_{t-m}$$

However, in other texts I've found, such as [this one](https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/basic-time-series-forecasting/holt-winters-method/) and [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing), the last one is given as

$$s_t = \gamma\frac{y_t}{l_t} + (1-\gamma)s_{t-m}$$

So, which is it?

Comment: I wish there was a way to tag users like @user:159 who is the author of that text (Rob Hyndman). I pinged him by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hyndman writes regarding additive model, seasonal component there is usually expressed in one of two ways, either:

$$
s_{t}=\gamma\left (y_{t} - l_{t-1} - b_{t-1}  \right ) + \left ( 1-\gamma \right )s_{t-m}
$$

or:

$$ s_{t}=\gamma^{*}\left (y_{t} - l_{t}  \right ) + \left ( 1-\gamma^{*} \right )s_{t-m}$$

where

$$
\gamma = \gamma^{*}\left (1-\alpha  \right )
$$

Similarly for multiplicative model we have two representations:

$$
s_{t}=\gamma \frac{y_{t}}{l_{t-1} + b_{t-1}} + \left ( 1-\gamma \right )s_{t-m}
$$

and

$$
s_{t}=\gamma^{*} \frac{y_{t}}{l_{t}} + \left ( 1-\gamma^{*} \right )s_{t-m}
$$

Apparently Hyndman just didn't bother providing the second one.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that in one case gamma is between 0 and 1, and in the other it's between 0 and 1-alpha. Thanks!